# How to restrict number of elements for row in angular ngFor rendering?

Tags: angular

**Problem:**

I have created an angular application in there I am trying to render some elements in 4 elements for a row. This is the code where I want to do it.

```
<div class="catgory-section">
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let category of categories;let i = index">
        <div class="row" *ngIf="i%5===0">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card bg-secondary shadow border-0">{{category.category}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code  I have written does not seem to work. I search for a lot to find out a solution to this problem but I was unable to do so can someone help me with this code. Thank you.

Comment: How about the following one: `*ngIf="i < 5"`. By applying this, you will have rendered rows once the index is less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

**Do it like this**

```
   <div class="category-section">
        <div class="container" *ngFor="let category of categories| slice:0:4;let i = index">        
    <div class="row" *ngIf="i<5">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card bg-secondary shadow border-0">{{category.category}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please don't use the ngIf here. You will overload the renderer.
The slice pipe is enough.